# presto sql filter last 24 hours

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to get a query that filters the date from the last 24 hours:

```
select *
    from tb
    where created_at > DATEADD('hour', -24, now())
    limit 100;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:24: Function dateadd not registered
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's ok, just the function name is wrong, it should be `date_add`

Docs:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score -3):

I don't think DATEADD is a postgres function, you could try this:

```
select *
   from tb
   where created_at > (now() - 24 * '1 hour')
   limit 100;
```

Comment: The questions is about PrestoDB, not Postgres.